# sitecore map a template page to a content page

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I am new to Sitecore and trying to create a new page on an existing website. I have made a copy of an  already existing template page and renamed it in a new folder, I then have created a new content page in the content folder. What I need to do now is link/map these two pages together.
I am sure it's simple but I can't find any info on how to complete this, any help would be much great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should have created your new page from your new template, but for now, you can change the page template by:

- Select your page in the content tree
- Go to the tab Configure
- Go to the chunk template
- Click to change

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I am confused by this, I have selected my page in the content tree and clicked on the configure tab but I can't see a chunk template in configure. Is there another way you could explain how to map/link the template to my content? As said I am new to sitecoe so apologies on my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the image made what you are saying clear. Unfortunately my screen looks a little different when I click on change from your screen shot. When I click on change it asked me to go through a whole process of changing a template rather then mapping/linking. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by mapping/linking?

Comment: Sorry I'll try & explain better.I have a folder called content in that which sits out side the website.I have a sub folder in the content folder that is filled with the content for the site e.g. a list of items.Then inside the website I have a template page e.g. Website/folder/template page. I believe it is possible to link this page to the content outside of the website so the content displays in the preexisting template format. So I am looking to map the path of the template to the content or link them together. I hope that makes more sense? Thank you and  I appropriate your tiem

Comment: I see, then you need to use dynamic URLs, read the following article:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2011/09/Wildcards-and-Data-Driven-URLs.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your Patience. This article was brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find out the change template as mentioned above, try the below steps:

```
1. Right-click on the particular content page.
2. Then click on **Insert**.
3. then click on **Insert from template**.
```

From here, you can choose which template you want the page to point to.

Hope this helps.